# create a Postgres function which returns a table

Tags: postgresql, function

I have this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getusers(in user_id numeric)
  RETURNS SETOF record
AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    ids character varying;
BEGIN



CREATE or REPLACE  TEMP VIEW test AS
         SELECT fx.*,EXTRACT(epoch FROM fx.time -(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL)::DOUBLE PRECISION as startTime
        ,EXTRACT(epoch FROM fx.time +(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL)::DOUBLE PRECISION as endTime
        -- ... maybe more columns and expressions ...
        FROM userlocation fx
        ;

CREATE or REPLACE  TEMP VIEW buffer AS
SELECT *,st_buffer(location,ul.buffer) as buffered from userlocation ul
        ;


 RETURN QUERY (
select "UserInfo".username as uid,"UserInfo"."userID" as uname,"UserInfo".id as id from "UserInfo" , (

  (SELECT f1."userID"--,f1."ID" as locationID
   FROM test f1
   WHERE EXISTS(
       SELECT *
       FROM test f2
       WHERE numrange((f2.startTime) :: NUMERIC, (f2.endTime) :: NUMERIC) &&
             numrange((f1.startTime) :: NUMERIC, (f1.endTime) :: NUMERIC)
             AND f2.locationtype = f1.locationtype
             AND f2."userID"=user_id
             AND f2.locationtype = 2)
           --  AND f2."ID" <> f1."ID")

  INTERSECT

  SELECT u1."userID"--,u1."ID"
  FROM buffer AS u1,
    (SELECT *
     FROM buffer ul) AS u2
  WHERE st_intersects(u1.buffered, u2.buffered) = true
        AND u1.locationtype = u2.locationtype
         AND f2."userID"=user_id
        AND u1.locationtype = 2)
      --  AND u1."ID" <> u2."ID")
  INTERSECT

  (SELECT f3."userID"--,f3."ID"
   FROM test f3
   WHERE EXISTS(
       SELECT *
       FROM test f4
       WHERE numrange((f4.startTime) :: NUMERIC, (f4.endTime) :: NUMERIC) &&
             numrange((f3.startTime) :: NUMERIC, (f3.endTime) :: NUMERIC)
             AND f4.locationtype = f3.locationtype

    AND f2."userID"=user_id
             AND f4.locationtype = 1)
          --   AND f4."ID" <> f3."ID")

  INTERSECT

  SELECT u3."userID"--,u3."ID"
  FROM buffer AS u3,
    (SELECT *
     FROM buffer ul) AS u4
  WHERE st_intersects(u3.buffered, u4.buffered) = true
        AND u3.locationtype = u4.locationtype

    AND f2."userID"=user_id
        AND u3.locationtype = 1)
       -- AND u3."ID" <> u4."ID")

  ) inter WHERE  inter."userID"="UserInfo".username);
    --Some code which build the ids string, not interesting for this issue

   -- RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname
   -- FROM public.users WHERE ids IN (' || ids || ')';






END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

this query supposed to give me a table, when I run the query part in  RETURN QUERY (....) it runs fine but when I run this function it gives me this error

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "f2"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function getusers(numeric) line 20 at RETURN QUERY
```

where I am doing wrong?can you please help me find the problem?
thanks

Comment: In the WHERE after the first INTERSECT you have f2."userID" but you only have u1 en u2 available.

Comment: @Eelke thanks for your answer,But why When I run the code from sql window in postsql it does not give me any errorS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2nd, 3rd and 4th part of your `INTERSECT` query you are trying to access a field from table `f2` in the `WHERE` part which is not visible there. You probably mean to respectively type:

```
u1."userID" = user_id -- second
f3."userID" = user_id -- third
u3."userID" = user_id -- fourth
```

Comment: thanks, But this query runs well before I convert it into a function

Comment: All your queries are separate and I honestly don't believe it. Please put your sample data and create tables needed to run the function into [sql fiddle script](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and share the link for further investigation.

Comment: wow.It was my mistake.I had added those line into my query and did not fixed them,It works now.Thanks